# алгоритм установки ежедневных и еженедельных задач

Tags: android, алгоритм, календарь

Писал ежедневник, в котором выставляются задачи. 
Задачи хранятся в БД по в таблице со структурой: "ид" "дата" "текст задачи".

Делается выборка по "дата" (в базе), и сравнивается с сегодняшней датой.

Вопрос: как сделать ежедневные задачи? Не заполнять же БД  на несколько месяцев вперед?)

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: В чем проблема заполнения бд на несколько месяцев вперёд?

Answer (score 1):

создай отдельные модели 

`daily-task
weekly-task  (здесь можно указать еще день недели)`

при отрисовке календаря делай выборку из общего календаря и из них.
Для ускорения, выборку daily и weekly можно кешировать, так как они будут редко меняться

Comment: Но как поставить статус "выполнено" такой задачи. 
Например после выполнения ежедневной задачи юзер выставляет ее как "Выполнено", и в этот день она больше не отображается.. Как это реализовать?

Comment: ну как вариант ты можешь ее "копировать" в календарь и там ставить статус уже

Answer (score 0):

Для периодических дат я бы использовал крон выражения. (правда, придется найти крон парсер для java)

То есть, у задачи должна храниться не дата, а выражение. После загрузки из БД, по нему можно пробежаться крон парсером и получить дату.

Единственное, будет запаркой сделать формирование этого выражения в графическом интерфейсе.